Jewelry and adornment
I have been reading a lot of Church Fathers like Tertullian or Clement of Alexandria and they all condemn women adorning themselves in any way and wearing jewelry is strictly prohibited by them. It seems very consistent with Bible New Testament views on the manner.

1 Timothy 2:9 (English Standard Version) - likewise also that women
should adorn themselves in respectable apparel, with modesty and
self-control, not with braided hair and gold or pearls or costly
attire,


1 Peter 3:3 (English Standard Version) - Do not let your adorning be
external—the braiding of hair and the putting on of gold jewelry, or
the clothing you wear—

People say a reliable method for interpreting the Bible is to consider whether the Church Fathers agreed with a particular interpretation, as they were closer to the Apostles and some were even their direct disciples. In contemporary times, however, these passages are often interpreted as advocating for modesty and moderation rather than a complete ban on jewelry and adornment.
Lots of people say that there is a lot of references to jewelry in Old Testament and in Ezekiel God Himself is using metaphor of jewelry to describe how He adorned Israel. On the other hand, some argue that in the Old Testament, God permitted certain practices because of the hardness of people’s hearts.
My question is: Should I believe my current church and priests on stand on jewelry (which is acceptable if worn in moderation), or should I believe the early Church Fathers' interpretation of the Bible? I am designer and jewelry is very important to me as my work field. I am personally scared I will end up in hell for not giving it up while I knew it was wrong.

Welcome to the group. Please read the Tour about what kind of questions we are looking for here. Sadly I’m voting to close this question because it does not deal with a specific biblical text

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out how to educate new users and the perhaps also the FAQs. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

@user92067 I have edited your question for clarity and included the verses you commented for suitability on the site. Feel free to review it and make any changes if needed.

Welcome to the site, and for this interesting question. I just have to wonder if plastic ear-rings, necklaces and bracelets would be given any serious consideration by anybody, in this context.

Could a modern application regarding women adorning themselves to look like the women they admire be the accumulating of more and more tattoos?

The question as asked is far more suited on https://christianity.stackexchange.com. VTC

In my opinion jewelry is mentioned because of its huge price back then? But some argue that it is because of outward adornment, but going this way even colorful top would be sinful. I read that pearls and gold were signs of wealth as their cost was crazy expensive, now I think it would be designer bags, rolex'es and expensive cars?

Interestingly, though this is straying into the 3rd Century, 2nd Century Apostolic Fathers texts are also open for examination as tertiary texts on BH.SE, so if you had any textual queries from Clement of Rome or other second century texts then you could ask questions about them. But as it stands this is currently topical and not anchored on a particular in-scope text.

The early church fathers were closer to the language of the Greek New Testament.  In that they are very helpful.  However, with interpreting cultural issues such as wearing jewelry and covering up one's hair, the early church fathers were in the same culture as the New Testament.  Thus, they don't express how to apply past cultural norms to our present culture. For interpreting such passages, we need to look at the general principles behind that cultural practice and apply those principles to our present culture thus modesty.
Here God commands the children of Israel to wear jewelry:

And I will give this people favor in the sight of the Egyptians; and when you go, you shall not go empty, but each woman shall ask of her neighbor, and any woman who lives in her house, for silver and gold jewelry, and for clothing. You shall put them on your sons and on your daughters. So you shall plunder the Egyptians.”
(Exodus 3:21–22, ESV2016)

Here James emphasizes a principle:

My brothers, show no partiality as you hold the faith in our Lord Jesus Christ, the Lord of glory.  For if a man wearing a gold ring and fine clothing comes into your assembly, and a poor man in shabby clothing also comes in, and if you pay attention to the one who wears the fine clothing and say, “You sit here in a good place,” while you say to the poor man, “You stand over there,” or, “Sit down at my feet,” have you not then made distinctions among yourselves and become judges with evil thoughts?
(James 2:1–4, ESV2016)

An example of a passage based on the culture of Paul's recipients of his letter is here.  Women covering their heads here isn't a matter of wearing hats but completely covering up their hair.

but every wife who prays or prophesies with her head uncovered dishonors her head, since it is the same as if her head were shaven.
(1 Cor. 11:5, ESV2016)

It's a matter of cultural modesty not a matter of sin in the act but sin in offending one's fellow Christian.

When you come together, it is not the Lord’s supper that you eat.  For in eating, each one goes ahead with his own meal. One goes hungry, another gets drunk.  What! Do you not have houses to eat and drink in? Or do you despise the church of God and humiliate those who have nothing? What shall I say to you? Shall I commend you in this? No, I will not.
(1 Cor. 11:20–22, ESV2016)

The motive can make an action sinful when the action in itself is not.

And so by your knowledge this weak person is destroyed, the brother for whom Christ died.  Thus, sinning against your brothers and wounding their conscience when it is weak, you sin against Christ.  Therefore, if food makes my brother stumble, I will never eat meat, lest I make my brother stumble.
(1 Cor. 8:11–13, ESV2016)

The emphasis on this passage is definitely that inward beauty is more important than outward appearance.

Do not let your adorning be external—the braiding of hair and the putting on of gold jewelry, or the clothing you wear—but let your adorning be the hidden person of the heart with the imperishable beauty of a gentle and quiet spirit, which in God’s sight is very precious
(1 Pe 3:3–4, ESV2016)

What Peter told them not to do were things that displayed wealth and encouraged discrimination as James described.

3:3. Hair was braided in elaborate manners, and well-to-do women strove to keep up with the latest expensive fashions. The gaudy adornments of women of wealth, meant to draw attention to themselves, were repeatedly condemned in ancient literature and speeches, and Peter’s readers would assume that his point was meant in the same way. See comment on 1 Timothy 2:9–10.
--
Keener, C. S. (1993). The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament (1 Pe 3:3). InterVarsity Press.

P.S. Eating certain foods will not send you to hell, but not eating food wdill send you to heaven quicker.

thank u so much <3 Can I also ask one more question - in verse 1 Peter 3 2 He says that women should have chaste and respectful conduct/way of life and then goes straight into telling that they adorning shouldn't be outward but inward. When u check the world chaste mean also plain unadorned, undecorated. Would that be a proof that Peter was saying that women shouldn't adorn themselves at all?

The word in 3:2 means holy, pure.  It only means chased by implication of the context ἁγνός, ή, όν (Hom.+) pure, holy
Arndt, W., Danker, F. W., Bauer, W., & Gingrich, F. W. (2000). In A Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament and other early Christian literature (3rd ed., p. 13). University of Chicago Press.

Does that mean for Apostols and people living then, unadorned women was chaste and adorned unholy?

SDA says every time Peter use "not this but that" it uses it as not this (at all) but that.. I am so confused, I have been told that if I ve been given enought light on this and I know what I should do but I am not doing it it is sin and I will end up suverly punished by God

@ user92067  See my edit.

thank you so much for it but is it true thatevery time Peter use "not this but that" it uses it as not this (at all) but that.. ?

Please consider that the "church fathers" were just men, many of them fallible.  They were not inspired, and they inserted their own biases and beliefs into their teaching of the scriptures.  The church fathers were a product of their early times in which they considered women were the conduit of sin entering the world, and thereby excused the men. Tertullian wrote in his book "De cultu feminarum" that they were the devil's gateway. (Source: https://scielo.org.za/scielo.php?script=sci_arttext&pid=S2074-77052022000100014)
Our study of the scriptures must be in context and from the first audience perspective.  Who was speaking, to whom were they speaking, and when were they speaking.  There is a significant phrase at the beginning of 1 Tim. 2:9.

in like manner also the women..." (YLT)

What "like manner"?   Verse 9 follows vs. 8 where Timothy was speaking about men praying in public.  So likewise, when the women would be praying in public they should be modestly dressed so as not to draw attention away from the words they were speaking.
Remember the time period of the 1st century AD when the pouring forth of the Holy Spirit happened at the day of Pentecost.  God's spirit - His words - were given to both men and women, and both men and women were prophesying, praying, and interpreting foreign languages (tongues / dialects) not only in the assemblies, but also in public.
Paul was not telling Timothy that women could not ever wear jewelry or braid their hair.  The point was to focus on what the Holy Spirit was conveying through the messenger, either men or women so as not to distract from that message.
1 Pet 3:1 begins with "in like manner" and vs. 3 is speaking of the inward appearance being more important than any outward appearance.  The time period of that old Roman empire was pagan in nature and the wealthy women especially had a habit of showing their wealth through their dress, their much braided hair which would require a hand maid or servant to help with, and LOTS of jewelry.  The women of that time were looked down upon by men, and jewelry, rich clothing and servants were symbols they used to elevate themselves in the eyes of their society.
The importance of both 1 Tim. 2:9 and 1 Pet. 3:3 was to focus on God, God's word, and inward purity.  These verses should not be used to teach that wearing any jewelry is forbidden.  Modesty in all things, not conforming to this world (Rom. 12:2) not trying to outdo others or show yourself above others, but to glorify our Father in heaven (1 Cor. 6:19-20; 10:31).
